# How to remove results with same value with django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a query that returns data that will be displayed in the browser as a line chart.
Depending on the period chosen, this can represent a rather huge number of results (~25K max).

Most of the time these values do not change, on average on 25 000 results I have about 8000 different values. I think it would be a real optimization if I only return these 8000 values instead of the 25 0000.

My Model:

```py
class TechnicalData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=80)
    value = models.CharField(_('Value'), max_length=80)
    value_type = models.CharField(_('Value type'), max_length=20)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(_("timestamp"))
    machine = models.ForeignKey("machine.Machine", 
                               verbose_name = _("machine"),
                               related_name="technical_data_machine",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("TechnicalData")
        verbose_name_plural = _("TechnicalDatas")
        ordering = ["-date_time"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If the "value" field does not change during a given period (date_time), I would like to remove the "duplicate/same" values.

Today I have this view:

```py
class TechnicalDataViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving technical data.
    """
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination

    def list(self, request):
        id_machine = self.request.query_params.get('id_machine')
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name')
        only_last = self.request.query_params.get('only_last')
        names = self.request.query_params.get('name__in')
        
        date_start = self.request.query_params.get('date_start')
        date_end = self.request.query_params.get('date_end')
        queryset = TechnicalData.objects.all()
        
        if id_machine:
            queryset = queryset.filter(machine__id=id_machine)
        if name:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name=name)
        if names:
            names = names.split(',')
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__in=names)
        if date_start:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date_time__date__gte=date_start)
        if date_end:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date_time__date__lte=date_end)
        if only_last:
            queryset = queryset.order_by('name', '-date_time').distinct("name")
        pagination = LargeResultsSetPagination()
        qs = pagination.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)
        serializer = TechnicalDataSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Is it possible to send only the different results?

Comment: You can group by on same values (field/column)

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a way to return distinct values of your queryset, django has a good method on queryset conveniently named distinct. here is a documentation on how to use it.

[django distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)